# Making window topmost inside app only

Tags: c#, winforms

I have app which opens several windows at the same time. One window (we'll call it `MainWindow`) is the main window of the app. From that window, I open several other windows using `Show()` method and set `Owner` property of those child windows to `MainWindow`. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) MSDN article, if the owner is set on those kind of windows, main window will ALWAYS be behind child windows

> An owner window can never cover an owned window.

The question is: is there a scenario which will allow me to retain parent-child relationship (I need this since I need to be able to iterate through child windows) and to have main window in front of all other windows in the app all the time? One key note: windows must be opened with `Show()`, and not `ShowDialog()` method.

I've experimented with `Topmost` property, using `Activate()` and `Focus()` methods, but haven't found a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a parent/child relationship and to be able to bring a parent window to front is to create a cusom form class, give it an property for your childs which you can use to iterate them and then simply inherit all your forms from your custom form class.
Then `Activate()` or `Focus()` should work.

Comment: `BringToFront` can't be used on `Window` objects, only on widgets.

Comment: @Fejs You're right. Btw. I changed and edited my answer

Comment: Proposed solution is difficult to implement. This is app with 100+ windows, which inherits different base windows, so changing all of them is not an option.

Comment: @Fejs Would it be an option to use the Form.Tag property to create the needed parent/child relationship rather than to inherit from a custom form class?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Then I belive there will be no other option than to change a lot of code in some way (custom form class, using Form.Tag property or switching to MDI with childs for iteration)